# change x limits of gg_season plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Let's say I have this plot and I want the x limits to be ["January", "August"], I would I go about it?

> *Code and picture credits to [Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3rd ed)](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)*

```
library(fpp3)

PBS |>
  filter(ATC2 == "A10") |>
  select(Month, Concession, Type, Cost) |>
  summarise(TotalC = sum(Cost)) |>
  mutate(Cost = TotalC / 1e6) -> a10

a10 |>
  gg_season(Cost, labels = "both") +
  labs(y = "$ (millions)",
       title = "Seasonal plot: Antidiabetic drug sales")
```

[image]

Comment: I would try filtering the months in the data frame before plotting, else use xlim() from ggplot https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html

Comment: @goblinshark the problem is that `gg_season` would complain since it requires the data to be filled, without gaps in the time series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gg_season()` plot helper is intended to provide a common time series plot with some flexibility, without being a general purpose plotting function.

To plot a subsets of the seasonal period, you may find it easier to create the plot yourself. Here's an example of how this can be done.

```r
library(fpp3)

PBS |>
  filter(ATC2 == "A10") |>
  select(Month, Concession, Type, Cost) |>
  summarise(TotalC = sum(Cost)) |>
  mutate(Cost = TotalC / 1e6) -> a10

a10 |>
  filter(month(Month) %in% 1:8) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = month(Month), y = Cost, colour = factor(year(Month)))) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = year(Month)), 
    data = a10 |> group_by(year(Month)) |> filter(month(Month) == min(month(Month))),
    hjust = 1
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8, labels = month.abb[1:8]) +
  guides(colour = "none") +
  labs(y = "$ (millions)",
       title = "Seasonal plot: Antidiabetic drug sales")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

(I would defer to Mitchell on this 100%, but here's a hack.)

```
a10 |>
  gg_season(Cost, labels = "both") +
  aes(x = as.numeric(Month) %% 12 + 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb, limits = c(1,8)) +
  labs(y = "$ (millions)",
       title = "Seasonal plot: Antidiabetic drug sales")
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! May I ask where do these breaks numbers come from?

Comment: I haven't delved into the `gg_season` source code enough to understand. I just tried `scale_x_continuous` and saw that 36:47 was the range I wanted.

Comment: The break numbers and limits is why I personally avoided this approach. Internally they are the months starting in 1973 (1973 is used for day of week reasons), and this is subject (and planned) to change. That said, when it eventually does change it'll be easier to achieve something like `scale_x_<>(limits = c(1, 8))`.

Comment: EDIT - If the data starts with a January I think that means we can use integer division to bring the numeric range down to a more intuitive 1-12 range.